# Cannot enable forking on github repo

Tags: github

I have a private repo. I noticed I cannot fork it. I cannot find any information that says I shouldn't be able to. When I go to Options the ability to fix this is disabled. I am guessing you need to pay or something which is fine, but it doesn't say that anywhere...

[image]

Cannot click!

Answer (score 66):

I think you are talking about your organisation's private repo, right? As I didn't find this checkbox for personal private repositories.

If so, then you need to:

1. go to your organisation's settings, Member privileges, and check "Allow forking of private repositories" [image: there].
2. go to your repo and you'll see "Allow forking" will be automatically checked after doing step 1,

   [image: like this].

The process is also described here:
https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-organization-settings/managing-the-forking-policy-for-your-organization

Answer (score 14):

As of 1/9/2022, I had to update "Member Privileges" in the Organization first:
[image]

And then, in the repository it seemed to automatically allow forking. Just note that you might want to update any other repository that you shouldn't be forked.
[image]

## References:

- https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-access-to-your-organizations-repositories/setting-base-permissions-for-an-organization
- https://github.community/t/private-repositories-option-grayed-out-under-member-privileges-in-my-organization/2029/6